# Substituting letters in an array

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, encryption

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $input = "test";

my @arr = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');

my @cip = ('%', '@', '!', '^', '*', '_', '+', '&', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', 'A', 'B', 'D', '$', '(', ')', '/', '|');

<do something here>

print $res;
```

The output should be according to the arrays: `B*AB`

The only problem is I don't know how to get there, I tried using s// from regex but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? You probably want to combine your two arrays into a hash.

Comment: You could do to show what you have tried for `<do something here` - it doesn't matter if it didn't work it just lets people know you aren't asking for them to code it for you!

Comment: The question needs clarification I think - otherwise we're just guessing as to how the output should be derived "according to the arrays".

Comment: I have no idea if this is related (see above comments) but I read through the (short) source of [`Text::UpsideDown'](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::UpsideDown) and found it interesting for (possibly) similar tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace char by char using hash look up table, where `@arr` elements are keys, and `@cip` are values. `"\U$1"` does upper case on captured string.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $input = "test";

my @arr = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');
my @cip = ('%', '@', '!', '^', '*', '_', '+', '&', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', 'A', 'B', 'D', '$', '(', ')', '/', '|');
my %h;
@h{@arr} = @cip;

(my $res = $input) =~ s/(.)/ $h{"\U$1"}  /ge;

print $res;
```

output

```
B*AB
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $input = "test";

my @arr = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');

my @cip = ('%', '@', '!', '^', '*', '_', '+', '&', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', 'A', 'B', 'D', '$', '(', ')', '/', '|');

# Loop through each index in the first array
for my $index (0..$#arr) {
    # search for the element at that index in the first array
    my $search = $arr[$index];

    # Replace it with the corresponding element in the next array
    my $replace =$cip[$index];

    # Search and replace, /i for ignore case and /g for replacing all instances
    $input =~ s/$search/$replace/gi;
}
my $res = $input;
print $res;
```

output:

```
Matt@MattPC ~/perl/testing/9
$ perl test.pl
B*AB
```

Comment: Well, you could. But why make it so difficult? :-)

Comment: some extra searches yeah, but tmtowtdi ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $input = "test";

my @arr = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');

my @cip = ('%', '@', '!', '^', '*', '_', '+', '&', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', 'A', 'B', 'D', '$', '(', ')', '/', '|');

my %translate;

@translate{@arr} = @cip;

$input =~ s/(\w)/$translate{uc $1}/eg;

say $input;
```

Comment: Does it make any sense to eval `"tr/@arr/@cip/"`?

Comment: @mpapec: for dynamic content, you have to eval tr

Answer (score 2):

Use a hash:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = "test";

my @keys = qw{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z};
my @vals = qw{% @ ! ^ * _ + & 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 A B D $ ( ) / |};

my %hash;
@hash{@keys} = @vals;

my $output = join '', map {$hash{uc $_} // warn "not found $_"} split '', $input;

print $output;
```

Outputs:

```
B*AB
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for good measure, an answer using the transliteration operator (`tr//`).

```
my @arr = qw(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z);
my @cip = qw(% @ ! ^ * _ + & 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 A B D $ ( ) / |);
my $arr = join "", @arr;
my $cip = join "", @cip;

my $res;
eval "(\$res = uc \$input) =~ tr/\Q$arr\E/\Q$cip\E/";
print "test => $res\n"; # B*AB
```

Unfortunately using variables in a `tr//` requires using eval. If the list is always going to be the same you could do something like `tr/A-Z/\%\@.../` instead and avoid the eval.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different transliteration example that is delimiter safe:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $input = "test";
my @arr   = qw(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z);
my @cip   = qw(% @ ! ^ * _ + & 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 A B D $ ( ) / |);

my $plaintext  = join '', @arr;
my $ciphertext = join '', @cip;

$_ = uc $input;
eval(sprintf("tr/%s/%s/", map { quotemeta($_) . "" } ($plaintext, $ciphertext)));
my $res = $_;

print "$res\n";
```